# jar file in persistence.xml not loaded by glassfish

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish, glassfish-3

folks,

i understand this is a silly question... bt i am so new to glassfish...

i have got an ear to deploy to deploy in glassfish 3. the ear has a jar and war inside already. the jar is a JPA jar and it has persistence.xml file. i have added a jar-file entry to load inside the persistence.xml file, with a jar entry which is not in the ear to be deployed. Where should i put the jar for glassfish to load it

( i have tried putting it in all lib folders in the glassfish dir and even inside various places in the ear only. there is something with lazy deployment i guess... so please suggest me a way to somehow solve this.)

thank for your time,

rajan

Comment: i hate to say this... 'life was so easy with Jboss'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, what i did was created a lib folder inside the ear, put the additional jar there and in the persistence.xml file inside the ejb jar, i had set the jar-file value as lib/jarname and it recognized...

thanks for yure time guys...

rajan...